# Make folium maps interactive with crossfolium (crossfilter library for folium)

Tags: python, crossfilter, folium

I tried to make an interactive tool from a data that I built using python/pandas.

I managed to make a great map using this tutorial for [folium](http://andrewgaidus.com/leaflet_webmaps_python/), but I would like to provide more interactivity, which lead me to crossfilters.

Crossfilters seem to be very powerful but require a lot of work and knowledge from other languages (d3-dc-leaflet).

Finally I found Crossfolium library that seems exactly what I need, but I can't find any help on the internet except from [these examples](http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/bibmartin/crossfolium/tree/master/examples).

**PROBLEM**: Copying the tutorial does not work for me. Keeps throwing that error in the last line, instead of showing up the map:

> The element is outputed: branca.element.Figure at 0x15a80750198

But right above I see:

> AssertionError: You cannot render this Element if it's not in a Figure.

No map is shown. If I try to save the figure (f.save(file_name)) the same error occurs.

**WHAT I TRIED**
Copy-paste the example either in Jupyter or IPython throws the same error.
Also tried to downgrade versions (folium 0.2.0 instead of 0.3.0)

**SUM UP**
I can't make crossfolium library working and can't find any questions at all about this library